# Can't see source code when an error occurs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

Sometimes I can't see the source code in Google Chrome debugger (V 58.0.3007.0 ).
This issue doesn't reproduce each time.

Error occurs:

[image: Error in console]:

Clicking on the error redirects me to 'Sources' tab in the chrome debugger. It displays a blank page.

[image: seeing blank page]

Can someone explain what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=354447), just refresh the page with devtools open and it should correct itself